# Is it possible to change the target namesplace of an AX 2012 AIF WebService?

Tags: web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, aif

If I create a AIF-WebService (custom or document) the targetNamespace is set to "http://tempuri.org/".
Is it possible to change that?

I've set the property "Namespace" in the service node in the AOT and I set in the configuration of the service the BindingNamespace in Service->ServiceName->Endpoints->DefaultServiceGroupEndpoint but that doesn't changed the targetNamespace.

And I don't know if it matters, we use the IIS as webserver.

Comment: did you find any possible solutions or came to any decisions? Could you please add that?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily change service namespace by doing two steps below:

1. Change "Namespace" property in the service node in the AOT.
2. Promote changes to WCF by going to the AifService form and pressing "Refresh" button.

Give it a minute and you will see change has taken its place.

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309574%28v=ax.50%29.aspx):

> If you make any changes to a service, or if you add a custom service
>   in the AOT, you must refresh the services for those changes to be
>   reflected in AIF.

[image]

Comment: I have in the "AIF services" form from your screen shot the right namespace, but the TargetNamespace is still "http://tempuri.org/".

Comment: There are number of ways to proceed, so it's essential to make sure we are discussing the same place. Could you clarify the place which has not been refreshed (screen shot could help). The possible steps could be to use _Update document service wizard_, or even to return schema by `getSchema()`